# Problem with CALL SYMPUT inside if then loop

Tags: sas

I'm encountering problems when I use the CALL SYMPUT function inside a if-then loop in SAS.

```
%LET food=kebab;
DATA _NULL_;
    IF &food.=pizza THEN DO;
        CALL SYMPUT('price',12);
        CALL SYMPUT('fat',5); 
    END;
    ELSE IF &food.=kebab THEN DO;
        CALL SYMPUT('price',6);
        CALL SYMPUT('fat',4);
    END;
RUN;

%put &food.;
%put &price.;
%put &fat.;
```

The variables actually take these values :

> food = kebab ; price = 12 (instead of desired value 6) ; fat = 5 (instead of 4)

Thanks in advance for any explanation.

Comment: Can you give us a working example? Your logic is going to consider `kebab` and `pizza` as two uninitiated variables. Also, if your macro variables are going to represent numbers, always safer to use `CALL SYMPUTX`.

Comment: What problems ? Did you look at the log ? Did you notice any messages about a variable named `kebab` ?  Are you trying to compare variables or literal values in the `IF` statement ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're using a data step, your IF statements need quotes. If it was %IF then your code would be closer to correct.

```
%LET food=kebab;
DATA _NULL_;
    IF "&food." = "pizza" THEN DO;
        CALL SYMPUT('price',12);
        CALL SYMPUT('fat',5); 
    END;
    ELSE IF "&food." = "kebab" THEN DO;
        CALL SYMPUT('price',6);
        CALL SYMPUT('fat',4);
    END;
RUN;

%put &food.;
%put &price.;
%put &fat.;
```

Another option is full macro logic, this will work in SAS 9.4M5+

```
%LET food=kebab;

    %IF &food.=pizza %THEN %DO;
        %let price = 12;
        %let fat=5; 
    %END;
    %ELSE %IF &food.=kebab %THEN %DO;
        %let price = 6;
        %let fat=4; 
    %END;


%put &food.;
%put &price.;
%put &fat.;
```

EDIT: If you're not on SAS 9.4M5+ which supports open macro code you need to wrap your logic in a macro.

```
%macro create_variables();

%global price fat;

%LET food=kebab;

    %IF &food.=pizza %THEN %DO;
        %let price = 12;
        %let fat=5; 
    %END;
    %ELSE %IF &food.=kebab %THEN %DO;
        %let price = 6;
        %let fat=4; 
    %END;


%put &food.;
%put &price.;
%put &fat.;

%mend;

%create_variables();
```

Comment: Thank you, your first solution worked.

I also tried to do it with %IF like you suggested,

`%LET food=kebab;
DATA _NULL_;
    %IF &food.=pizza %THEN %DO;
        CALL SYMPUT('price',12);
        CALL SYMPUT('fat',5); 
    %END;
    %ELSE %IF &food.=kebab %THEN %DO;
        CALL SYMPUT('price',6);
        CALL SYMPUT('fat',4);
    %END;
RUN;

%put &food.;
%put &price.;
%put &fat.;
`
However after the "else if" statement I have this error : **ERROR: Nesting of %IF statements in open code is not supported. %IF ignored.**

Is the code wrong or SAS 9.4 is not enough ?

Comment: You need M5, not M4, check your version with `proc product_status;run;` If not, you need to run it in a macro and you need to use %LET not CALL SYMPUT since you're no longer in a data step.

Comment: Or use %SYSCALL https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=mcrolref&docsetTarget=n1xdrl171qpcr6n0zbskwm17wvct.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en